# "Server Manager -> Configuration -> Local Users and Groups" is not available in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-controller

I'm trying to follow instructions from [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc515176%28v=cs.70%29.aspx), but I can't seem to find **Server Manager** -> **Configuration** -> **Local Users and Groups**. Here's what I get:

[image]

What am I missing there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since this is a domain controller, you don't have local users and groups.

Other than the Directory Services Restore Mode account, there are no "local" accounts on a domain controller. Only domain accounts.

Comment: Oops. I see. Thanks. So I need "Active Directory Users And Computers" for this, right? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc515176%28v=cs.70%29.aspx

Comment: Yes! You should find it in your Start menu, under Administrative Tools.  Or you can run dsa.msc, etc.